# Организация очереди потоков

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Ситуация: есть некоторые данные к которым обращаются разные потоки, необходимо как-то блокировать доступ к данным для других потоков, пока с ними работает текущий.

При всем этом доступ к данным должен осуществляться по очереди для всех потоков.

**Вариант решения**:
при работе с данными ставим флаг (`isBusy` - данные заняты другим потоком).

Когда сторонний поток приходит смотрит этот флаг, если занят то добавляется текущий поток в очередь и засыпает. Как рабочий поток освобождает данные, сбрасывает флаг, и будит поток из очереди.

**Вопрос такой**:
какие могут быть проблемы при данном решении, как будет сделать лучше? И подскажите как правильно усыпить на неопределенное время и разбудить поток? (методы `Suspend` и `Resume`, я так понял, устаревшие, так что их использовать не хочу).

Comment: Потоки только читают данные?

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы любой поток мог получить данные только после того как все потоки обработали предыдущую порцию данных?

Comment: Потоки могут править данные, это что-то типа хранилиища с которым работаю разные потоки, они берут от туда данные, обрабатывают и обратно сохраняют.

Comment: @Serg, `ReadWriteLock` пробовали?

Comment: ReadWriteLock не пробовал и не слышал

Comment: Ну, проблема в том, что другие потоки простаивают, пока один работает. (Допустим, первый поток обрабатывает задание долго, а остальные очень быстро — тогда им придётся ждать.) Не лучше ли завести producer-consumer queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два стандартных способа блокировать доступ к общему ресурсу:

Первый - [lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) на один и тот же объект из всех потоков. Один поток схватит блокировку, остальные будут ждать пока он ее отпустит. Пример из MSDN:

```
class Account
{
    decimal balance;
    private Object thisLock = new Object();

    public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
    {
        lock (thisLock)
        {
            if (amount > balance)
            {
                throw new Exception("Insufficient funds");
            }
            balance -= amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Второй - использование [Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private static Mutex mut = new Mutex();

public void DoWork()
{
    if (mut.WaitOne(1000)) // ждет и захватывает mutex
    {
        // do work

        // release
        mut.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Объектов блокировки (и способов организации могопоточности) много. В зависимости от схемы работы с данными стоит посмотреть в сторону

- [Concurrent Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) - если у вас потоки заняты выполнением постоянно докидываемых заданий.
- [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) - если есть разделение на потоки-читатели и потоки-писатели, и читатели могут работать одновременно.

Стандартные примитивы синхронизации не гарантируют порядок выполнения. Т.е. то, что поток первым начал ждать Mutex, еще не означает, что он первый получит его после освобождения. Если важен порядок, то придется использовать что-то вроде:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public sealed class QueuedLock
{
    private object innerLock;
    private volatile int ticketsCount = 0;
    private volatile int ticketToRide = 1;

    public QueuedLock()
    {
        innerLock = new Object();
    }

    public void Enter()
    {
        int myTicket = Interlocked.Increment(ref ticketsCount);
        Monitor.Enter(innerLock);
        while (true)
        {

            if (myTicket == ticketToRide)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Monitor.Wait(innerLock);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref ticketToRide);
        Monitor.PulseAll(innerLock);
        Monitor.Exit(innerLock);
    }
}
```

использовать как:

```
// создать один общий объект для всех потоков
// сделать static или передать в каждый из потоков как параметр/через замыкание
QueuedLock queuedLock = new QueuedLock();

// в коде каждого из потоков:
try
{
    queuedLock.Enter();
    // работа с данными
}
finally
{
    queuedLock.Exit();
}
```

<sub>взято с enSO: [Is there a synchronization class that guarantee FIFO order in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/961904/1988244), где тоже взято с какого-то ныне умершего сайта</sub>

Comment: если использовать Mutex то очередность потоков не гарантируется ведь ? если несколько потоков жду освобождения, нет гарантий что тот кто первый обратился получит доступ первым ?

Comment: @Serg не гарантируется. Порядок можно сделать с помощью concurrent queue, отдельного управляющего потока  и  набора autoreset event-ов, по одному для каждого потока. Если никто не предложит готового решения - попробую набросать чуть попозже

Comment: @Serg но вообще это будет практически ваш вариант, только с нормальными евентами для приостановки потоков вместо стремных suspend и resume

Comment: @Serg с телефона не получается добавить в ответ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961869/is-there-a-synchronization-class-that-guarantee-fifo-order-in-c

Comment: Я так понял concurrent queue потокобезопасная очередь,  а что за autoreset evet'ы ?

Comment: @Serg объекты, [которые можно ждать из одного потока](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx), а сигналить - в другом. обычно используется вместо бесконечных циклов в ожидании флага "можно идти дальше". посмотрите ответ, я добавил туда код по ссылке. он вроде вполне рабочий и решает вашу проблему.

Answer (score 2):

То, что вас интересует - называется примитивы синхронизации.

Примеры: [Monitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) и [lock statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx), [ReaderWriterLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock(v=vs.110).aspx), [Semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx) и [SemaphoreSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslime(v=vs.110).aspx).